# Stuck on Learnstreet Ruby Training. Lesson 7.8 Introducing && Operator

Tags: ruby

The lesson asks to implement the method get_range.  Per their instructions:

Your function should return:

1. The string "1 - 50" if the number is between 1 to 50
2. The string "51 - 100" if the number is between 51 to 100
3. The string "101 - 200" if the number is between 101 to 200
4. The string "greater than 201" if the number is greater than 201

This is the code i wrote, and it keeps saying its wrong.  any insight as to whats incorrect?

```
def get_range(number)
    if number >= 1 && number <=50
      "1-50"
    elsif number >=51 && number <= 100
      "51-100"
    elsif number >=101 && number <= 200
      "101-200"
    elsif number >= 201 
      "greater than 201"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

So I just went through the other lessons to get to this one.   Your answer is very close, but you need a space before and after the `-` in the responses.

```
def get_range(number)
    if number >= 1 && number <=50
      "1 - 50"
    elsif number >=51 && number <= 100
      "51 - 100"
    elsif number >=101 && number <= 200
      "101 - 200"
    elsif number >= 201 
      "greater than 201"
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! That was a huge help!